# PromQL: change label values for grouping - remove unique parts

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

In Grafana I have this metric: `http_server_requests_seconds_count`. It has several labels I'm interested in, one of which is `uri`. I'd like to group fetched metrics by method + URL to plot response times.

The problem is, some of the `uri` label values contain unique values (UUIDs) as some endpoints accept entity IDs as path variables. Naturally, this will not only ruin my plans to group response times by URL, but also SIGKILL my Grafana page because of too many unique results.

I found a `label_replace()` filter which, according to [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace), create a new label and

> If the regular expression doesn't match then the timeseries is returned unchanged.

This quote is the part where I'm having trouble.

Suppose I have the following `uri` values:

- /some/path
- /get/user/id/290ef4ae-644e-11ee-a8bd-1b2c4def1377
- /home/index.php

I'm trying to run this PromQL:

```
sum(label_replace(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[$__rate_interval]), "uri2", "$1", "uri", "^(.+)(/([a-fA-F0-9]{0,8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4,12}){4})")) by (method, uri2)
```

The query copes well with the UUIDs and removes them clean. But the other URLs (/some/path and /home/index.php) disappeared.
If I try to make the regex non-greedy `^(.+)(/([a-fA-F0-9]{0,8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4,12}){4})*?`, the UUID part is not getting removed and the `uri2` label now contains the same values as `uri`.

How can I fix my query?

Grafana v9.5.12

Comment: You should make first group non-greedy, second - optional, and add eol anchor: [`^(.+?)(/([a-fA-F0-9]{0,8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4,12}){4})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/qXGkiB/1)

Comment: Additional point: your current approach, with full uri in labels is **very** wasteful in terms of Prometheus' storage. Every unique label set results in a distinct time series. I strongly advise you to consider removing ids from labels on exposure (by your application)

Comment: Thank you. That worked.  As for the second point - I agree. That's in my TBD for later (the client isn't yet complaining about this inefficiency). For now, I just need to make the current setup work.